# Web Audio API - record to MP3?

Tags: javascript, html, mp3, wav, web-audio-api

I am asking because I couldn't find the answer anywhere.
I have successfully implemented [RecorderJS](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs) in order to record microphone input in JS. However, the recorded file is WAV which results in large files. I am looking for a way to record with JS directly to MP3, or encode the bits somehow to MP3 instead of WAV.

How can it be done? Is there a Web Audio API function that can do that or JS MP3 encoder of some sort?

Comment: I only know of the other way round decoding, meaning going from MP3 to WAV - https://github.com/audiocogs/mp3.js. You will probably need to dig into https://github.com/kripken/emscripten to get a wav to mp3 encoder in JS.

Comment: Thanks, I am looking into Emscripten but I still don't see how it can help.

Comment: Well you need to get some C-Written wav-mp3 decoder, and than decode wav into mp3 in the browser :)

Answer (score 13):

The only Javascript MP3 encoder I've seen is https://github.com/akrennmair/libmp3lame-js, which is a port using emscripten.  It's supposed to be slow, and I've never used it.

I don't know of any natively-written Javascript MP3 encoders, and encoding is not covered by the Web Audio API.

Answer (score 10):

There's a library written in pure javascript, called lamejs. To encode mp3s from raw audio. It is much faster than emscripten compile of libmp3lame. https://github.com/zhuker/lamejs

Example usage:

```
lib = new lamejs();
mp3encoder = new lib.Mp3Encoder(1, 44100, 128); //mono 44.1khz encode to 128kbps
samples = new Int16Array(44100); //one second of silence
var mp3 = mp3encoder.encodeBuffer(samples); //encode mp3
```

Comment: lamejs worked well for me. It seems to have no trouble keeping up with realtime, eliminating the need for worker threads. I created a test page at [my site](https://aws.nlited.org/mp3.htm) with a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I was frustrated with this problem, and existing solutions, so I came up with something simpler:

https://github.com/sb2702/audioRecord.js

**Usage**

Create a recorder object (async because requires user permission)

```
    Recorder.new(function(recorder){ 

    });
```

Start recording

```
         recorder.start();
```

Stops recording

```
         recorder.stop();
```

Export as mp3

```
         recorder.exportMP3(function(mp3Blob){ 

            console.log("Here is your blob: " + URL.createObjectURL(mp3Blob));

          });
```

Mostly based on RecorderJS, but changed some things around to export to mp3 files, and to not have to muck around with AudioContext  / navigator.getUs

Answer (score 2):

I have found a nice library with live demos: [MediaStreamRecorder](https://github.com/streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder)

One of demos is here: [Audio Recording](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/msr/audio-recorder.html)

[RecordRTC](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC) is also can be useful but MSR it seems is easier to start with.

Answer (score 1):

Encoding into smaller formats is currently only supported by Firefox:

- http://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-record/MediaRecorder.html
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder

`Chrome        Firefox (Gecko)  Internet Explorer  Opera           Safari (WebKit)
Not supported  25.0 (25.0)     Not supported      Not supported   Not supported`

AFAIK only OGG is supported. But better OGG than WAV.

Answer (score 1):

To record mp3 using javascript without any other framework using a web worker, you can use this project: https://github.com/nusofthq/Recordmp3js which is also very well explained here:

http://audior.ec/blog/recording-mp3-using-only-html5-and-javascript-recordmp3-js/

With this, it's also possible to write to a .mp3 file and to make it downloadable.

Answer (score 1):

I made an easy-to-use wrapper for lamejs for my project. It records to MP3 in mono or stereo at any bitrate. You just tell it what AudioNode you want to record.

```js
    import { Mp3Recorder } from './Mp3Recorder.mjs';

    let recorder = new Mp3Recorder();

    await recorder.configure(inputAudioNode, channels, bitRate);

    recorder.start();

    recorder.pause();

    recorder.resume();

    let bytes = await recorder.getRecordedSize();

    let mp3 = await recorder.stop();
```

For instance, to record the user's microphone in mono at 128 kbps:

```js
    const audio = new AudioContext();
    let micStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
    const mic = audio.createMediaStreamSource(micStream);

    await recorder.configure(mic, 1, 128);
    recorder.start();
    
    // ...later, when you're ready to stop recording:
    let mp3 = await recorder.stop();
```

[Live demo and source here.](https://github.com/EricTetz/Mp3Recorder)