# Music file encoding in Javascript or PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, html5-audio

I'm trying to figure out how to encode an audio file in javascript.

I would like to do something like

play sound > wait 1 second > play another sound > wait one second.

Then take all of that and turn it into a wav file or even better an mp3.

Anyone know how I can go about doing that? Is it even possible?

Or do I need to use a server side php language like PHP?

If so why, and how would I do it with PHP?

Comment: You want to process audio files using js? I don't think it's capable for that. I used FFMpeg library for video files processing in PHP. But it can be used for audio too.

Comment: That is really funny people are down voting this. If you asked what THIS stands for in c# you would be at +100 by now.

Comment: @snowYetis Maybe because with C# or any other server-side language you would be capable of doing that, which is not the case of Javascript.

Comment: @MelanciaUK JS is not server side, but what about Node.JS or a like framework that allows server side JS?

Comment: @snowYetis The OP didn't mention Node.JS, Angular, Backbone, etc. The question is about Javascript as it is.

Comment: @MelanciaUK JS could be an all encompassing category. What is Node, Angular, Backbone, etc based from? JS! I leave you with that thought. Lighten up, SO peeps.

Comment: Along with the tags html and html5-audio it's reasonable to assume the question is about browser-based JS. That said, there's no reason why browser-based JS couldn't do audio processing. (It's just much easier to do server-side in some other language that has more libraries dedicated for such tasks.)

Comment: @snowYetis It's not all about lighten up. It's about keeping the questions well categorized. If you tag a question with browser (client-side) categories, and ask for a task that needs server-side to be completed, your question is invalid. A simple re-tag and re-wording would make it valid and avoid downvotes.

Comment: There is no reason why this question should be considered invalid or off topic for browser-based Javascript.

Comment: @Juhana I have done a lot of projects as a consultant where the client was not able to install a framework on their server. It is insane, because these were very large corporations. In these cases I had to use JS.

Comment: @MelanciaUK perhaps you don't realise that Javascript can now be run server side?

Comment: @iKode Please read all my comments before assuming something I didn't say.

Comment: @iKode, Just to clarify the question: first the user or someone will select a few clips, play those with 1 second intervals, and then when they are happy you want to generate an mp3 of those sound clips?

Answer (score 8):

As far as I am aware you will need to encode the audio file on the server so you will need something that you can call with PHP.

Your best bet would be something like FFmpeg which needs to be installed on the server and then you can call it through the command line.

Here is a very useful article on the FFMpeg WIKI about calling the command-line tool from PHP:

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Using%20FFmpeg%20from%20PHP%20scripts

**Edit**

After some digging through google there is a JS MP3 encoder: libmp3lame.js

Here is the GIT page: https://github.com/akrennmair/libmp3lame-js

Here is an article about recording audio using HTML5 and JS. It does cover recording but the process of encoding once that is done is the bit you will be interested in:

http://nusofthq.com/blog/recording-mp3-using-only-html5-and-javascript-recordmp3-js/

Answer (score 5):

Your current best option is to use [**Aurora.js by Audiocogs**](https://github.com/audiocogs/aurora.js/) for audio decoding.
As for audio encoding, see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16924096/1470607), audio encoding is not covered by the Web Audio API, but see the thread for one possible library port and other possible helpful clues.

Answer (score 2):

In HTML5 use :

Base64 encode your audio data using [readAsDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader#readAsDataURL%28%29) or [some base64 encode](http://scotch.io/quick-tips/js/how-to-encode-and-decode-strings-with-base64-in-javascript)r.

then:

```
var Sound = (function () {
    var df = document.createDocumentFragment();
    return function Sound(src) {
        var snd = new Audio(src);
        df.appendChild(snd); // keep in fragment until finished playing
        snd.addEventListener('ended', function () {df.removeChild(snd);});
        snd.play();
        return snd;
    }
}());
```

to use:

```
var snd = Sound("data:audio/wav;base64," + base64string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Worths mentioning that you can write a program in C or Python that does the encoding and can convert this afterwards to JS using [**Emscripten**](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki).

From the project's homepage:

> Emscripten is an LLVM to JavaScript compiler. It takes LLVM bytecode
>   (which can be generated from C/C++ using Clang, or any other language
>   that can be converted into LLVM bytecode) and compiles that into
>   JavaScript, which can be run on the web (or anywhere else JavaScript
>   can run).
>
> Using Emscripten, you can:
>
> - Compile C and C++ code into JavaScript and
> - Run code in languages like Python as well, by compiling CPython from C to JavaScript and interpreting code in that on the web
>     run that on the web.

Might be not the best option for you but definitely worths mentioning.
Also you might want to take a look at a naïve benchmark: https://github.com/tvararu/asm-benchie